# Stop logging specific accounts in aws organizational trail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-organizations

I have a CloudTrail trail for all accounts on my organization and want to stop logging for some of them. Is there any way to stop logging specific accounts not for all ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question it seems like you're using centralized logging for CloudTrail.

If this is the case then login into member accounts where you want to stop logging and delete the respective trail. If the trail was enabled by cloudformation then delete the CF stack.

After that Go to your centralized logging account **-->** S3 bucket where your member account trails are logged **-->** Edit bucket policy **-->** In the resource section remove the arn of the account where you deleted the trail.

If you're not using centralized logging then login into respective accounts nd delete the trails. Empty the S3 bucket and delete the bucket if you don't need logs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [organisation trails](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/creating-trail-organization.html) then this is not possible. It is either enabled for the whole org or not at all.